# Get width of a view using in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, frame

I need to get width of a rendered view in `SwiftUI`, which is apparently not that easy.

The way I see it is that I need a function that returns a view's dimensions, simple as that.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(timer.name)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
        Text(timer.time)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
            .opacity(0.5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The only available mechanism to get the dimension of a view, that is auto-resized by SwiftUI, is the `GeometryReader`.
The `GeometryReader` is a proxy view that returns the dimensions of the container in which your view gets rendered.

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State var size: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("VStack width: \(size.width)")
            Text("VStack height: \(size.height)")
            
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                HStack {} // just an empty container to triggers the onAppear
                    .onAppear {
                        size = proxy.size
                    }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

The printed size is the dimension of the `VStack`.

### How to get the dimension of a View

Now that we know that the `GeometryReader` gives us the size of the container, the usual follow-up question is: how do I use it to get the size of a specific view?

To do this we need to move the geometry reader one level below our targeted view. How? We could add an empty background that gets the size of the targeted view and sends this information back to a `Binding`.

Let's create a `SizeCalculator` `ViewModifier` so that we can use this functionality on every view:

```swift
struct SizeCalculator: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear // we just want the reader to get triggered, so let's use an empty color
                        .onAppear {
                            size = proxy.size
                        }
                }
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func saveSize(in size: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
        modifier(SizeCalculator(size: size))
    }
}
```

The job of the `SizeCalculator` is to add a `GeometryReader` as the background of our target view. On appear, so after SwiftUI has rendered the `content`, it will send the size back to the `Binding`.

Usage:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State var size: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("text width: \(size.width)")
            Text("text height: \(size.height)")
            
            Text("hello")
                .saveSize(in: $size)
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image: how to get the size of a view in swiftUI]

Comment: If I am not to calculate dimensions, then how would I go about implementing a layout similar to this https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4m47u3fhup7o8j/2.png?dl=0

Comment: I mean, I need to know the width of a cell to be able to calculate the numbers of cells in a row.

Comment: @MaxPower mmh I suggest you to open a new question with a title like that "How to calculate number of cells in a Row" anyway try to look at this https://github.com/Q-Mobile/QGrid

Comment: @GiuseppeSapienza thanks for this nice solution. Do you know why the call of ```DispatchQueue.main.async {...}```is necessary in order to work? I would have thought that ```makeView()``` is running on the main thread already.

Comment: @Lindemann no it's not necessary anymore. I have updated the answer with a better approach.

Comment: This seems like a brilliant idea, but how would one use it to capture the entire screen size for use by views in the body? I tried the Color overlay trick but the other views all seemed to render before the $size was set.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced not quite sure to follow, but you might try adding a `ZStack` with inside a `VStack { Spacer() }`. You can use the VStack to obtain the size of the screen and then pass this info down to your views

Answer (score 47):

Getting the dimensions of a child view is the first part of the task. Bubbling the value of dimensions up is the second part. `GeometryReader` gets the dims of the parent view which is probably not what you want. To get the dims of the child view in question we might call a modifier on its child view which has actual size such as `.background()` or `.overlay()`

```
struct GeometryGetterMod: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var rect: CGRect
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        print(content)
        return GeometryReader { (g) -> Color in // (g) -> Content in - is what it could be, but it doesn't work
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // to avoid warning
                self.rect = g.frame(in: .global)
            }
            return Color.clear // return content - doesn't work
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rect1 = CGRect()
    var body: some View {
        let t = HStack {
            // make two texts equal width, for example
            // this is not a good way to achieve this, just for demo
            Text("Long text").overlay(Color.clear.modifier(GeometryGetterMod(rect: $rect1)))
            // You can then use rect in other places of your view:

            Text("text").frame(width: rect1.width, height: rect1.height).background(Color.green)
            Text("text").background(Color.yellow)
        }
        print(rect1)
        return t
    }
}
```

Here is another convenient way to get and do something with the size of current view: `readSize` function.

```
extension View {
  func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    background(
      GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
        Color.clear
          .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
      }
    )
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
  }
}

private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var commonSize = CGSize()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .border(.yellow, width: 1)
            .readSize { textSize in
                commonSize = textSize
            }
        Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            .frame(width: commonSize.width, height: commonSize.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In reference to Giuseppe Sapienza's answer, by adding an .onChange modifier to SizeCalculator

```
.onChange(of: proxy.size, { oldValue, newValue in
    size = proxy.size
})
```

the ViewModifier will respond dynamically to changes in the size of the view being measured.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `size = newValue`?

Comment: I think it doesn’t need `onChange`. If the view changes, `onAppear` will trigger again.

Comment: First, yes. It should be size = newValue. Sorry about that.

Comment: However, the onChange is necessary, at least in my use case. I use the saveSize modifier on a VStack containing multiple Texts. I use a sheet to update the Texts (rather than making them TextFields). (This is a SwiftData app, and the Texts display the value of attributes.) In this case (where the contents of the VStack is changed by a sheet), onAppear is not called when the sheet is dismissed. The onChange modifier is needed to detect the size change in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way to get the width of a view using `GeometryReader`. You need to create a state variable to store the width, then surround the desired view with a `GeometryReader`, and set the width value to the geometry inside that width. For instace:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var width: CGFloat = 0.00 // this variable stores the width we want to get
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Text(timer.name)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .onAppear {
                        self.width = geometry.size.width
                        print("text width: \(width)") // test
                    }
            } // in this case, we are reading the width of text
            Text(timer.time)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .opacity(0.5)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the width will change if the target's view also changes. If you want to store it, I would suggest using a let constant somewhere else. Hope that helps!

Comment: **// in this case, we are reading the width of text** No, we are not. We are reading size of VStack